# Laravel Queries

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables **items** and **branch_item**

I need to optimize and query this,

```
$test2 = DB::table('items')
            ->join('branch_item', 'items.id', '=', 'branch_item.item_id')
            ->select('items.minimum', 'branch_item.item_quantity')
            ->where('branch_item.branch_id',9)
            ->where('branch_item.item_quantity','<' ,'items.minimum')
            ->get();
return $test2;
```

What I need is to query the items that is below in minimum in quantity of certain branch.

I can do this using foreach but it loads so slow so I think I need to use join tables.

Comment: What's a "*joint* table" ?

Comment: join tables, sorry nop77svk

Comment: Did you use relations in your Eloquent models?[See here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#relationships)

Comment: I need to do it with all items not just single items, column with other columns

Comment: rephrase the question. perhaps give example of what you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
$test2 = DB::table('branch_item')
            ->join('items', 'branch_item.item_id', '=', 'items.id')
            ->select('branch_item.id','items.id','items.minimum', 'branch_item.item_quantity')
            ->where('branch_item.branch_id',9)
            ->having('items.minimum', '>' ,'branch_item.item_quantity')
            ->get();
```

Our team debugs it already, what the problem is we use Where instead of Having,
There is a big difference between having and where.